# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

First of all, my SQLite Database is working fine as far as adding, deleting, etc.

I could load the ArrayList in Oncreate method just fine.  However,

When I tried the following:

add new item to the ArrayList,

```
Arraylist.clear();
LoadArrayList();   //reload the list
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it threw in the force close with "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6"

When I tried this:

```
Arraylist.clear();
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The ListView showed up nothing (that's what I was expecting), so it does its job.

The conclusion:

**Why did it give me the force close when I tried to reload the list with this**:

```
Arraylist.clear();
LoadArrayList();
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

???????

Furthermore, I did check the database for the new item to see if it was saved.  The new item was added and saved properly. I do not understand why my LoadArrayList method can not read the new item...

Can someone please help?

**Is there anyway other way to refresh the list with the new changes?**

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit: added code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

…….

…..

    try {           
        Open_SQLITE_DATABASE();         
        LoadArrayList();    //Load the list at start    and IT WORKS …..                                    }       
    catch (Exception e) { }

…..

…..

     listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    listView.setAdapter(Arraylist);

    listView. setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            .....


    }

    });

….

….


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.loadbutton:
        Arraylist.clear();
        LoadArrayList();   //NOT WORKING ??????
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     return true;
   }

...

...

Public void LoadArrayList(){

    Cursor cursor = SQLITE_DATABASE.getWritableData().query(SQLite_Database.getDatabaseTable(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor != null)
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String POSITION = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLite_Database.Position));
            Arraylist.add(POSITION);            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post your code in loadarraylist?

Comment: `LoadArrayList()` should be lower case -- please check coding conventions. That aside, it looks as though you're trying to access an array element that isn't there. If the length is 6, you have indices 0..5 available. Double-click on the log-cat entry, and it'll take you to the line where it's failing. Most likely, it'll become self-evident from there.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum index you should try to access is 5. index numbering starts from 0.

`length=6; index=6` means you are trying to access index 6, which does not exist. Check your LoadArrayList() logic.

Comment: I do understand that.  I had 6 items in the list.  I added the 7th, clear and reload the list.  It gave me that error.  What I don't understand is it loads the list just fine in Oncreate method.  Why can't it see my new item which is added to the Database properly?  Thanks

Comment: post the code of `LoadArrayList()` then. Can only guess without seeing the code.

Comment: @IamAGoodPerson you seem to have messed up the scope of `Arraylist`. It is a private variable inside `LoadArrayList()`. Yet you are using it outside the method. So the `Arraylist` variable you have initialized inside the method is different from the one outside. You need to fix that.

Comment: You are right.  The Arraylist initialization inside the LoadArrayList() method should not be there.  I messed up when I copied the code to this website.  The weirdest part is that when I reopen the app, the new item shows up without a problem.  When I tried to make a new item, then reload the list without closing the app, it throws in the force closer error.  For some reasons, it can't see my new item until I close and reopen the app.  I checked the database and the new item is added and saved correctly.  The new item is there, but it can't see it until I reopen the app.

Comment: @IamAGoodPerson It would be helpful if you step into the code in debug mode and find out which exact line is throwing the error. The error is too broadly defined for now.

Comment: I will have to try that.  I understand and thank you for trying to help anyway.  I very appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.loadbutton:
        Arraylist.clear();
        LoadArrayList(); 
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listView.setAdapter(Arraylist);   //This is needed to prevent the force close

     return true;
   }
```

Basically, listView.setAdapter(Arraylist) was missing.  I hope it helps someone else.